# Display full type in ghci

Tags: haskell, ghci, bytestring

I have a variable of `ByteString` type. I want to see which package it belongs to. This could be useful for ByteString types because there are several different implementations in different packages.

For instance, I have following piece of code:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BSL
json :: String
json = "{\"document\":{\"name\":\"doc1\",\"content\":\"content1\"}}"
```

I want to get full package when I do `ghci> :t BSL.pack json`. What I get is `BSL.pack json :: ByteString` while I want something like `BSL.pack json :: Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8`. Is there any way to get this kind of information at the ghci prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GHCi should use the same syntax you can use in your file. That is, if you import `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8` unqualified you will get `ByteString` unqualified, otherwise you should get the qualified type.

Check all your imports in your Haskell file: is something importing the `ByteString` type in an unqualified way?

As you can see below, I can not reproduce your issue in a small GHCi session:

```
> import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BSL
> let a :: String ; a = "aa"
> :t BSL.pack a
BSL.pack a :: BSL.ByteString
```